# 2 rewriterules not blocking each other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I´m trying to make work 2 rewriterules, however one of them is not working as expected when the other is active.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /$1?language=spanish [R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?language=spanish [R=302]
```

The second one is always working no matter what. The first one doesn´t work unless the second is not active.
How do I make these work together?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to add the 'L' flag to the R=302 to ensure no more rules are applied. So the resulting flag set would be [R=302,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `L` flag and add a condition in 2nd rule to avoid further execution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /$1?language=spanish [R=302,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^language=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?language=something-else [R=302,L,QSA]
```

L flag ends current rewrite loop and injects the rule for further processing.

Comment: Thanks! I don´t know why but in this case I need to remove L flag, otherwise this doesn´t work at all. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the first rule at all and your condition is only getting applied to the first rule and not the second.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?language=spanish [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I needed the second part in this case, otherwise it didn´t work. Thank you anyway Jon!